# Length of array of strings

Tags: c

How can we determine the length of an array of strings when we don't know the length?

For example in this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    char names[3][10] = { “Alex”, “Phillip”, “Collins” };

    for (n = 0; n < 3; n++)    
        printf(“%s \n”, names[n]);
}
```

`n < 3` is assuming you know the length of the array but how can you determine it's length when we don't know?

I have tried a few alternatives such as:

```
int arraySize() {
    size_t size, i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char names[3][10] = { “Alex”, “Phillip”, “Collins” };

    size = sizeof(names) / sizeof(char*);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d - %s\n", count + 1, *(names + i));
        count++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("The number of strings found are %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

**or**

```
for (n = 0; n < sizeof(names); n++)
```

but they all error out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Given what you know about `sizeof`, what do you think `sizeof names` produces? What does `sizeof names[0]` produce? What does `sizeof names[0][0]` produce? Do those give you any idea?

Comment: I know very little tbh I am only starting with C now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by *they all err out*.

There is a syntax issue in the code posted as you use guillemet characters instead of double quotes: `“Alex”` should be `"Alex"`.  This could be a side effect of your cut/paste method to post the code, but nevertheless a potential issue.

Your approach using `size = sizeof(names) / sizeof(char*);` is right but the type is incorrect: `names[0]` is not a `char *`, it is an array of 10 characters. You should use `size = sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]);` which works for all arrays, regardless of the type.

Here is a modified version where the length of the array is determined by the compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char names[][10] = { "Alex", "Phillip", "Collins" };
    int i, length = sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)    
        printf("%d: %s\n", i + 1, names[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- you could use `size_t` instead of `int` for array length and index variables, but it is only necessary for very large arrays and the `printf` conversion specifier would be `%zu` for a value of type `size_t`.
- it is less confusing to use `length` for the length of an array and reserve size for sizes in bytes obtained from `sizeof()`.

Comment: thanks! And yes it was a copy and paste issue, my code has the right syntax.  Nevertheless, this sorted my issue, thanks very much

Comment: I have tried to use my function as an "external function" to main but getting loads of errors now:

```int arraySize(char names[]) {
    size_t size, i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    size = sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d", count);
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    char names[3][10] = {"Alex", "Philip", "John"};
   arraySize(names);
}```

any ideas?

Comment: The `names` argument is not an actual array, the function receives a pointer to the first element, from which the length of the original array cannot be determined. `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` can only be used with an array, not a pointer or a function argument.

Answer (score -1):

first every string is ended with a special character '\0'
means

> {'A','L','E','X','\0'}

even you haven't put '\0' there but compiler put it there for it convenient

```
int lenght(char *str){
int count = 0 ;
for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++){
    count++ ;
}
return count ;
```

}

use this function to count your string length
like :

```
int main(){
char names[3][10] = {"Alex", "Phillip", "Collins"};
printf(“%d \n”,lenght(names[1] );
return 0 ;
}
```